# npm throw errors when installing dependencies of hardhat

Tags: ganache, hardhat, npm, chai

when installing those dependencies:

```
npm install ethers hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle
chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
```

Those errors occurred:

```
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rimxjoudi/.npm/_logs/2022-02-24T12_02_36_700Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I get rid of those errors, any help please!

Comment: There is a good chance you're not using the correct version of node. I'd use node version 16.x.x. instead of the latest 17.x.x. Version 17 has some breaking changes. You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to easily change node versions.

Failing that, it's complaining that you're getting a socket timeout -- perhaps you can take a look at the `/home/rimxjoudi/.npm/_logs/2022-02-24T12_02_36_700Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: Pro tip: consider starting from my [hardhat-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template) and you won't have to install any dependencies any longer, when you're bootstrapping a new project at least.

Answer (score 2):

Hardhat migrated waffle plugin to the chai detailed info here

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle#migrating-away-from-hardhat-waffle

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install --save-dev hardhat
2. npx hardhat
3. npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
4. npx hardhat test or compile

**don’t use**
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers     ⇒  it throws an error